# SQL group by date gang within data range

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's the best way to query a table like below in sql?

I need to determine the `PackListGrp` variable (`PICKONLY` or `JITPICK`)  by the `expectedshipdate`, `deliverymethod` for a given `OrderID`.

When the `expectedshipdate` is within 2 days for each line item then the `PackListGrp` for would be `JITPICK`.

When the `expectedshipdate` is > 2 days, the the Pick `DeliveryMethod` would be `PickOnly` and the `PSIEST` would be `JITPICK`.

Basically i'm just trying to gang order line items determined by the expectedshipdate.

Thanks

```
OrderID ExpectedShipDate    Sku     DeliveryMethod  PackListGrp
66064   13-Sep-18         22-81506  Pick            PickOnly
66064   13-Sep-18         878-85487 Pick            PickOnly
66064   13-Sep-18         5-4878-   Pick            PickOnly
66064   13-Sep-18         3-020-02  Pick            PickOnly
66064   13-Sep-18         7-209-23  Pick            PickOnly
66064   13-Sep-18         7-206-05  Pick            PickOnly
66064   13-Sep-18         7-305-08  Pick            PickOnly
66064   13-Sep-18         7-567-20  Pick            PickOnly
66064   18-Sep-18         6-104-24  Pick            JITPICK
66064   19-Sep-18         TCC_KS    PSIEST          JITPICK
66064   17-Sep-18         TCF-DK    PSIEST          JITPICK
```

Comment: Please add to your post, `expected results`.

Comment: within 2 days compared to what date?

Comment: @LukStorms the 2 days would be within any of dates in the expectedshipdate . if the expectedshipdate on the  7-567-20 row was  16-Sep-18 then the PackListGrp would be JITPICK

Comment: @LukStorms I guess this is the key is finding that start date to compare to.... i think I can use the Pick rows as the starting date since they're always the minimum date, then i could add a where parameter to look forward 2 days and just use the case expression to apply the logic.

Comment: Why not just use the minimum date then?  MIN also has a window function. I.e. `MIN(ExpectedShipDate) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want a `case` expression?

```
select t.*,
       (case when datediff(day, t. expectedshipdate, getdate()) <= 2
             then 'JITPICK'
             else 'PICKONLY'
        end) as packlistgrp
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff for the quick response.... that's what I as kindof thinking but since this is at line item level wouldn't I need to cross apply or cross join for the same order somehow?

Comment: @user8165942 . . . The expected ship date appears to be on each row, so the logic appears to be within a single row.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand right you want to act your PackListGroup As a computed Field.

if it rights, this code will help you

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ExpectedShipDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN 'JITPICK'
        WHEN ExpectedShipDate > DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) THEN 'PickOnly'
        ELSE 'JITPICK' END AS PackListGrp
FROM
    yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks @Alireza for the quick response.... that's what I as kindof thinking but since this is at line item level wouldn't I need to cross apply or cross join for the same order somehow?

Comment: I could not understand your question but if you want to join this table with other tables and use this field for ordering your query you have to use in like this  `SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ExpectedShipDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN 'JITPICK'
        WHEN ExpectedShipDate > DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) THEN 'PickOnly'
        ELSE 'JITPICK' END AS PackListGrp
FROM
    yourTable inner join secTable on yourTable.yourField = secTable.another field order by PackLIstGroup desc`